# Pandas apply style on groupby hierarchy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

Pandas style keyword only works on rows or columns. Is it possible to split it according to sublevels.

For example

```
np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Types': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=['Names','V1','V2','V3'])],
               axis=1)

df['Types'][0:7] ="Dang"

df['Types'][7:] ="Fang"

df['Names'][0:3] ="Andy"

df['Names'][3:8] ="Flower"

df['Names'][8:] ="Avril"

df2 = pd.groupby(df,['Types','Names']).mean()
df2
```

Now I want to highlight the max value according to sublevel

```
def highlight_max(x):
     return ['background-color: yellow' if v == x.max() else ''
                for v in x]

df2.style.apply(highlight_max,axis=0,subset=['V1'])
```

It will highlight in this case max value in column 'V1'. I want basically two max values as per the group levels. So I want to highlighted values. Is there any simple way to do that? None of the intro material covers this basic feature.

Answer (score 4):

You need return `DataFrame` of colors for set styles. So need create new `df` with same index and columns with default values - here empty string and then change values by condition created by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and compare by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) (`==`):

```
def highlight_max(x): 
   c1 = 'background-color: yellow'
   c2 = '' 
   m = x.groupby(level=0)['V1'].transform('max').eq(x['V1'])

   df1 = pd.DataFrame(c2, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
   df1.loc[m, 'V1'] = c1
   return df1

df2.style.apply(highlight_max,axis=None)
```

[image: pic]